# Why CKEDITOR.inline couldn't send much string data into database in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, fckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm currently used Codeigniter2.2 (latest version) and I'm using CKEDITOR with Inline option (Click on textarea to modify paragraph) and The my database table row data type is longtext as images

[image]

and here is my user interface for user insert data into database 
[image]

I got error logical as the a little text can insert to database as Textarea_1
But login text in textarea_2 can't insert into database.

NOte:if I don't used Text Editor I can insert 2MB amount of text size into database

So How could I send big size of text size into database using CKEDITOR in codeigniter?

Please help

Comment: "I got error logical" What does that mean? Do you get an error message? Does it fail silently? Do you feel a chill? Do you get a letter from your Database saying "Yeah I can't do this"? Can you capture the traffic to see what is actually being sent? Are there any console messages? Any server logs?

Comment: Now it was solved thanks for your supported and I will try to read tutorial on Ckeditor website too because have more professional feature too